# HR Styling - Only working in Firefox, how to make it work for IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have this code

```
<hr style="margin-top: 5px; color: #ada95b; width: 500px;"/>
```

However this is only working in Firefox, and not working on my versions of Chrome and IE. What way is best to style them and they will work in all browsers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

best way is removing the border and putting a color to background.. i.e.

```
<hr style="margin-top: 5px; height: 2px; border: none; background: #ada95b; width: 500px;"/>
```

Comment: I think this is the easiest way to make it work, without modifying the most code, and I tested it out and it works nicely.

Comment: is this still the best way to customize a `<hr>` tag?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the `color`, browsers treat it differently, you should also set `background-color`.

This is a quite old article, but might still help.

http://www.sovavsiti.cz/css/hr.html

You can also get some ideas here:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/a/style_hr_tag.htm

Comment: Thanks mate, nice article. I ended up using the background-colour to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

As I have tested your code with different browser (IE6 - 8, FF4 Chrome 10+) it is working fine. Although the problem it looks different to each other. You can solve this by adding a

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

on your page. But as I have tested IE6 and IE7 is not giving the same results as the others browser unless change color to `background-color` as other post suggested. See more information about `DOCTYPE`.

- [Recommended list of Doctype declarations](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)

The Second solution is you need to check what is the browser in use then apply the style for that browser.

- [Browser Detection and Cross Browser Support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Browser_Detection_and_Cross_Browser_Support)

Comment: How does doc type affect this? I am using <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> atm.

Comment: Declaring a DOCTYPE a browser will render the standard format content correctly. http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype

Answer (score 1):

For consistent display you can use a DIV with no height and either a top or bottom border.

```
<div style="margin: 5px 0; border-top: 1px solid #ada95b; width: 500px;"></div>
```