# How to decorate an <hr/> tag

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I want to have an horizontal ruler with the following characteristics:

```
align:left
noshade
size:2
width:50%
color:#000000
```

If the above attributes were not deprecated, I would use:

```
<hr size="2" width="50%" noshade style="color:#000000" align="left" />
```

I'm now thinking of using the style attribute only. Are there any tricks to make the HR render the same in several browsers?

---

EDIT:

From the answers, I remade my `<hr />` tag to:

```
<hr style='background-color:#000000;border-width:0;color:#000000;height:2px;line-height:0;text-align:left;width:50%;'/>
```

However, in Firefox, the **text-align:left** property seems to have no effect, as the horizontal rule appears centred. It works fine in Opera and IE, though. I experimented my code here:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_hr_test

Any trick to make it left-aligned?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619566/hr-styling-only-working-in-firefox-how-to-make-it-work-for-ie-and-chrome

Comment: See the first comment on: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-hr-styling/

Answer (score 10):

In 2015, most browsers seem to render `HR` as a block element with zero height and 1px inset border. You can change the properties like this:

```css
p { font: italic large serif; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<p>hr size="2" color="palevioletred" width="50%" align="left"</p>
<hr style="border: 1px solid palevioletred; 
           margin-right: 50%;           ">

<p>hr size="2" color="palevioletred" width="50%" align="right"</p>
<hr style="border: 1px solid palevioletred; 
           margin-left: 50%;">

<p>hr size="1" color="palevioletred" width="50%" align="center"</p>
<hr style="border-width: 1px 1px 0;
           border-style: solid;
           border-color: palevioletred; 
           width: 50%;
           margin-left: auto;
           margin-right: auto;">
```

Comment: Why would you prefer DIV to HR? Thanks.

Comment: A DIV is not a HR and provides no fallback for simple display-programs. You should use a HR where a HR is meant to be placed…

Comment: @John: good question for which I do not have a *good* answer. It is easy to apply box-model formatting on a DIV and get the expected results compared to applying the same on a HR and then testing in different browsers.

Comment: @feeela: objection duly noted.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question:

"Any trick to make it left-aligned?"

I would just add 'display: inline-block;' to the style attribute in your previous code.
Your completed code would look like this:

```
<hr style = 'background-color:#000000; border-width:0; color:#000000; height:2px; lineheight:0; display: inline-block; text-align: left; width:50%;' />
```

I tested this in Chrome, IE, and Firefox, and it worked in each. Further documentation and browser compatibility can be found here: [CSS2 - The Display Declaration](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)

On a side note, it would be best to add this style to an external or internal style sheet instead of adding it inline. This way, you can have a standardized hr element for your entire website, and it keeps your style declarations separate from your document layout.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a picture, then type this code into CSS???

```
            hr {
        height:43px; /*(image height)*/
        width:50%;
    background-image:url("hr-tag-image.png"); /*Your image file*/
/*Demo: https://heckles.typrograms.com */
}
```